# Licensing of Kendo UI

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

Its bit of non-programming question but I need advice on this.  (Tried contacting Telerik but no response)

We are planning to integrate Kendo with one of our single tenant SaaS product.  Each of our customer will get separate instance of this.  We have bought Kendo standard one developer license.  Do our customers also have to buy this license?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The end user agreement can be found [here](http://www.telerik.com/purchase/license-agreement/kendo-ui-professional). In short, you'll have to buy a kendo license for each developer (or contractors) working for you.  The number of client that will use your product doesn't matter:

> “Licensed Developers” (i) are limited to the number of Your employees
>   or contractors authorized by You to use the Software to develop
>   software specifically for You and (ii) must correspond to the maximum
>   number of seats You have purchased from Telerik hereunder. This means
>   that, at any given time, the number of Licensed Developers cannot
>   exceed the number of seats that You have purchased from Telerik and
>   for which You have paid Telerik all applicable License Fees pursuant
>   to this Agreement. The Software is in “use” on a computer when it is
>   loaded into temporary memory (i.e. RAM) or installed into permanent
>   memory (e.g. hard disk or other storage device). Your Licensed
>   Developers may install the Software on multiple machines, so long as
>   the Software is not being used simultaneously for development purposes
>   at any given time by more Licensed Developers than You have seats.

Comment: Thanks @the_black_smurf